# iPhone errors in console related to NSTimer?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am writing an app that uses NSTimer on a non-repeating basis. It sets a timer for about 30 seconds and runs `.invalidate()` either before the time is up or from within the method that the NSTimer eventually calls.

I'm noticing the following output, normally repeating 5 or so times whenever I use the timer:

```
Jul 25 12:08:47 iPhone timed[62] <Notice>: (Note ) CoreTime: Want active time in 41.53min. Need active time in 8333.20min. Remaining retry interval: 0.000000min.
Jul 25 12:08:47 iPhone UserEventAgent[26] <Error>: validateAndAddDefaults(com.apple.timed): End Time (inf) > now (491166527.7) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_WINDOW_MAX_TIME_FROM_NOW_SEC (3024000.0) + BACKGROUND_TASK_AGENT_JOB_TIME_ERROR_MARGIN (300.0)
Jul 25 12:08:47 iPhone timed[62] <Notice>: (Error) CoreTime: Error requesting proactive time check job
```

Am I doing something wrong? App seems to be working as intended.

Here is how I'm creating the timer:

```
let timeRemaining = UIApplication.sharedApplication().backgroundTimeRemaining
let timeoutIn = [timeRemaining - 3, 30].minElement()!
self.timeoutTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeoutIn, target: self, selector: #selector(ACMEService.completeUpdate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Here is how I'm tearing it down:

```
if let timer = self.timeoutTimer {
    timer.invalidate()
    self.timeoutTimer = nil
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Why do you think the error has anything to do with NSTimer?

Comment: Because it happens reliably when I tear down the timer in my app and because the error relates to timing.